# Why my java compiler think the initialized array is an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, java-stream, reduce

I'm using stream reduce in Java and I wrote this code:

```
 ArrayList<CacheElement>[] initialArrayList = initArrayWithArrayList(newCacheCapacity);
        Arrays.stream(cache).reduce(initialArrayList, (acc, cacheChainingList) -> {
            cacheChainingList.forEach(cacheElement -> {
                int index = calcIndexByKey(cacheElement.getKey(), newCacheCapacity);
                acc[index].add(cacheElement);
            });
            return acc; // return the updated accumulator
        });
```

My compiler is referring my accumulator (acc)  as an **Arraylist** type rather than a **primitive array**. I expect it to recognize acc as ArrayList[] type.
Please help me figure it out :)

I tried to access acc as an array but got a compilation error:

> Array type expected; found: 'java.util.ArrayList<org.example.myCacheService.cache.CacheRepository.CacheElement>'

Comment: Does the error happen at `acc[index].add(cacheElement);`, or elsewhere?

Comment: @BoppreH Yes, exactly there

Comment: A primitive array is this kind of array: int counts[]. A primitive type like int, double, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce method signature you are using here is the following :

```
public abstract T reduce( T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator )
```

T is the Type your are streaming on, in this case ArraysList as I believe cache is an array of ArrayLists.

So it is normal that in the lambda statement defining your BinaryOperator : (acc, cacheChainingList)->{...},

acc would be of type T, which is ArrayList

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why T is not an array of ArrayLists.

Comment: it is just how reduce works :) it reduces your stream of T to a single T element, I have the feeling your use case requires a stream.collect rather than a stream.reduce, a stream.collect will give you back a collection of T, in this case an array of ArrayLists.